# Magento 2.3 REST API Json response format issue

Tags: magento2.3, rest-api, json, response

**How I can change the `json` format from**

```
[
    [
        {
            "success": [
                {
                    "code": 200,
                    "response": {
                        "collection": [
                            {
                                "id": "1",
                                "title": "camp1",
                                "description": "vishal desc",
                                "start_date": "2019-02-28 00:00:00",
                                "end_date": "2001-02-22 00:00:00",
                                "status": "0",
                                "desktop_image": "images\\yourope.jpg",
                                "mobile_image": "images\\yourope.jpg",
                                "created_at": "2019-02-28 06:50:25",
                                "updated_at": "2019-03-11 10:16:48",
                                "other": null
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

To this

```
{
   "data": [
        {
            "success": [
                {
                    "code": 200,
                    "response": {
                        "collection": [
                            {
                                "id": "1",
                                "title": "camp1",
                                "description": "vishal desc",
                                "start_date": "2019-02-28 00:00:00",
                                "end_date": "2001-02-22 00:00:00",
                                "status": "0",
                                "desktop_image": "images\\yourope.jpg",
                                "mobile_image": "images\\yourope.jpg",
                                "created_at": "2019-02-28 06:50:25",
                                "updated_at": "2019-03-11 10:16:48",
                                "other": null
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: assign your result to a multidimensional array with key 'data'

Comment: Thanks for reply. I try out this but is not working if i am not wrong may be i need to put this "data" while final JSON has been return by system as we doing in D:\wamp64\www\artoreal\app\code\core\Mage\Api2\Model\Renderer\json.php file public function render($data)
    {
        /* Added By Nihilent For Customize JSON response*/
        //return Zend_Json::encode($data);
        if($data['messages']){
            return json_encode(array('data'=>array_values($data)));
        }else{
            return Zend_Json::encode($data);
        }
    }

Comment: Hi vishal, can you post the method how you rendering , so i can check it

Comment: public function getinfo($id) {
                $post = $this->_advertisementFactory->create();
  $collection = $post->getCollection();
  foreach($collection as $item){
                        if($item['id']==$id){
   $data[]=$item->getData();
                        }
  }                
        $response['data'][]=array('success'=>array(array('code'=>200,'response'=>array('collection'=>$data)))); 
        return $response;
    }
    
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer:

1. **Overwrite this file**:

   > \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Json.php
2. **We are overwrite this file** : di.xml

   > preference for="Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Json" type="Evolve\Apirenderer\Webapi\Rest\Response\Renderer\Json"
3. Replace this function by this
   Orignal:

   ```
   public function render($data)
   {
       return $this->encoder->encode($data);
   }
   ```

   **Replace By This**

   ```
   public function render($data)
   {
      return json_encode(array('data'=>array_values($data)));
   }
   ```

   ***You will get above response***.

Comment: please format the code, hard to understand